# Reverse for 'category_list' not found. 'category_list' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, html, django

i want to do pages for my categories,but when i added get_absolute_url,i got issue that url pattern is doesnt exist.I have done it with functions,and previously didnt work with classes,like ListView.And this is a little bit problem for me

**views.py**

```
    model = Category
    active_tab = 'category_list'
    template_name = 'products/category_list.html'


    def get_ordered_grade_info(self):
        return []

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['grade_info'] = self.get_ordered_grade_info()
        return context
```

**models.py**

```
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(_('Slug'), unique=True)

    PARAMS = Choices(
        ('following', 'following'),
        ('price_to', 'price_to'),
        ('price_from', 'price_from'),
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('category_list', kwargs={'category_slug': self.pk})
```

**urls.py**

```
    url(r'^$', views.CategoryListView.as_view(), name='category_list')
```

**html**

```
{% block content %}

    <h2>Categories</h2>
    <div class="list-group">
        {% for category in category_list %}
            <a href="{{ category.get_absolute_url }}" class="list-group-item">
              <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{ category.name }}</h4>
            </a>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Comment: If your url is in specific app and you've specified [app_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/#example-1) in urls.py then you've to specify `reverse('myapp:category_list', kwargs={'category_slug': self.pk})`

Comment: @AnkitTiwari
i knew this problem,yeah,i have 3 apps in my project,but when i use 'products:category_list', it still doesnt work

Comment: Did you defined app_name inside urls.py

Comment: yes i did,if you meant urls.py in app not in cfg

Comment: You've to check for **app_name** inside `myapp/urls.py` in your eg. it should be `products/urls.py`